# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while trying to read a .hoodie.properties file in Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read a file in Databricks, which contains a .hoodie.properties file. This is the code.

class TLHudi:
def **init**(self,spark,route):
self.spark = spark
self.route = route

```
def create_df(self):
    data_generator = self.spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hudi.QuickstartUtils.DataGenerator()

    inserts = self.spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hudi.QuickstartUtils.convertToStringList(data_generator.generateInserts(10))

    df = self.spark.read.json(self.spark.sparkContext.parallelize(inserts, 2))
    return df

def read_df(self):
    return self.spark.read.format("org.apache.hudi").load(self.route)

def write_data(self,df):

    hudi_options = {
        'hoodie.table.name': "Test",
        'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'uuid',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': 'partitionpath',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.table.name': "Test",
        'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'ts',
        'hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism': 2,
        'hoodie.insert.shuffle.parallelism': 2
    }

    df.write.format("org.apache.hudi") \
        .options(**hudi_options) \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .save(self.route)
```

I then execute this commands. Inside the path is where the .hoodie.properties is.

a = spark.read.format("hudi").load("/temps/awss3/documents/file")
a.show()

In this last row I keep getting this error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileStatusCache.putLeafFiles(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;[Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus;)V

How can I fix this error?

I am using Databricks 12.2 LTS with Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12 and org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3-bundle_2.12:0.13.1